# Converting char to ASCII and display in C#?

Tags: c#, ascii, type-conversion

How to convert `char` to `ASCII` and display in textbox in `C#`?

For Eg :

i have char `a` and i want to convert this to ASCII-code `95` and display it in `textbox`.

noted : tools =  visual Studio express edition 2010

Comment: Hey, you should read [Ask], the [FAQ] and take the [Tour].

Comment: okay. thanks for advise

Comment: You can't in general convert a `char` value to an ASCII value, because there are only 128 ASCII values, but tens of thousands of legal `char` values. See the marked duplicate for information about dealing with the subset that _is_ possible to convert.

Comment: When you say "ASCII" but don't mean the ASCII character set or its one encoding, people rightly misunderstand. The generic term for "ASCII-code" is "character code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int AsciCode = (int)'c';
string AsciStr = AsciCode.ToString();
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this;

```
string value = "a";

// Convery your string to ascii.
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
Char chr = 'a';
int Ascii = chr;
TextBox1.Text(Ascii.ToString());
```